# Q: After adding a new item to a list, is there a way/workflow to automatically add new item to another list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, discussion-board, list-item

I am hoping someone could direct me to the right path on being able to do the following.

I have an "issue tracker" list, and a "Team Discussion" list. When adding a new item to the "issue tracker, I would like for SharePoint to automatically add a new item in "team discussion" list that I will use to relate/connect to the item associated with in the issue tracker using the lookup column.

I'm doing this to utilize discussing topic at work in a more appreciate area such as the "team discussion" list instead of using emails back and forth with colleagues and our partners.

I know that I can do this manually, but I'm hoping to utilize a workflow to automate this process.

Here are the current steps:
1. Create new item in "Issue tracker" with a topic.
2. Create new item in "Team Discussion" relating to above topic.
3. Edit Issue Tracker item with related item in Team Discussion list using "Lookup" column
4. Edit Team Discussion item with related item in Issue Tracker list using the "Lookup" column.

I hope this make sense and appreciate your help and direction.

Comment: Any idea to post a reply to a discussion via a workflow? I want to post changes to the Task meta data directly into the list (Eg assigned to or due date changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two lists, Issues and Discussions with a lookup column on each referring to the other list (so, in the Issues list the lookup column points to Discussions and in the Discussions list the lookup column points to Issues).

Then, you create a worflow attached to the Issues list with the following configuration:

[image]

Inside the "Create item in Discussions" action, you need to assign the Title value (eg: Discussion for [%Current Item:Title%]) and the Issue lookup column value to Current Item:ID.

Then, you add an action of type "Set field in current item" where you set the Discussion lookup column value to the Variable:create value.

As a last step, you need to set the workflow to start automatically upon item creation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This sounds very great. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: is this a question? if so, I would suggest that you ask another question so that others can have a look as well

Comment: Here's the question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89088/i-cant-change-the-return-field-as-in-spd-for-a-lookup-type-column

Comment: I do have the same requirement. Could you please describe the steps for the below two processes. 1. lookup column on each referring to the other list
2. create a workflow.